# Deducting a userpoint from the author of a quiz for each question answered correctly by another user

Tags: userpoints, quiz

My site uses the quiz and userpoints modules so that users take quizzes and receive a userpoint for each correct answer. That part works fine.

What I want to achieve is to have the same number of userpoints deducted from the author of the quiz - i.e. the quiz creator 'pays' the points to the users who answer their questions correctly.